# Authentication Details Not Provided REST API POST Request

Tags: java, django, rest, api

I'm posting to an API server and I'm getting the following reply:

```
Server Response: {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

I'm writing the requests in Java and I'm not sure exactly why it's saying credentials were not provided.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 hconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
 hconn.setRequestProperty( "Accept", "application/json" );
 if( urlconn instanceof HttpsURLConnection )
 {
    String encoded = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode( ( username + ":" + password).getBytes()));
    String auth = "Basic " + encoded;
    urlconn.setRequestProperty("Encoded Authorization", auth );

 }
```

Where `hconn` is of type `HttpURLConnection`

This is the only relvant snippet that you guys need. Are there properties i'm missing to set here?

I know the server response is from a Django framework but the documentation is not clear on spotting what IS required to prevent this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Authorization` is the correct request header name and not 'Encoded Authorization'. So, you should set

```
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);
```